# How to auto play next song with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, addeventlistener

Hi I am trying to automatically play the next song when the current playing song is over.

I also wanted to know how I could make sure the playlist starts from the beginning when the last song ends.

Thank you !

```js
var songs = [
  "song1.mp3",
  "song2.mp3",
  "song3.mp3",
  "song4.mp3"
];

var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;
var len = currentSong.length - 1;

function playSong() {
  song.src = songs[currentSong];
  song.play();
}

// play the next song when current song ends
song.addEventListener("ended", function playNextS() {
      currentSong++;
      if (currentSong == len) {
        currentSong = 0;
        playSong();
      }
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div class="songCover"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="about">
    <div class="songTitle"></div>
    <div class="Artist"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Your are not using array in correct way

```js
var songs = [
  "song1.mp3",
  "song2.mp3",
  "song3.mp3",
  "song4.mp3"
];

var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;
var len = songs.length;

function playSong(index) {
  song.src = songs[index];
  song.play();
}
song.addEventListener("ended", function playNextS() {
      currentSong++;
      if (currentSong == len) {
        currentSong = 0;
        playSong(currentSong);
      }
      else{
        playSong(currentSong);
      }
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div class="songCover"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="about">
    <div class="songTitle"></div>
    <div class="Artist"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @lbnelaiq thanx That worked ! do you know how I can make sure it loops back to beginning at the end o the

Comment: it will loop back beacuse there is a condition of checking if the currentsong index is equals to lenght of songs in array then set the current song to 0, else play the song